# Error in initializing members of a structure

Tags: c, struct, initialization, malloc, declaration

Following is a **program for initializing members of a structure** in c

```
struct stack
{
    int *a;
    int top;
    int size;
}s;

void init()
{

    const int size =10; /*s.size=10;*/  /*const int s.size=10*/
    s.a=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    s.top=0;    
}

int main()
{
    init();
    printf("Initialization done !\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

**Q1** : In `init` method instead of `const int size=10` when I wrote `s.size=10` , I got an error "**size was not declared in scope** " , but I have already declared `size` in `stack` struct .I was able to initialize `top` in the same manner Then why the error ?

**Q2** : In  `init` method I am getting **correct output with** `const int size=10` . I am confused , in this statement how are we able to access `size` member of the struct `stack` without using a struct variable , shouldn't it be `const int s.size=10`?

Comment: Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: The compiler is complaining not about `s.size=10`,but it is about the `size` in `s.a=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));` when you remove `const int size=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your confusion  is because you've used the same variable name `size` twice,

1. as a structure member variable
2. as a local variable in `void init()`.

Please be noted, these two are *seperate* variables.

The `size` member variable in `struct stack` is a member of the structure. You need to access a member variable by either `.` or `->` operator [Yes, even if the structure is global].

OTOH, the `int size` in `void init()` is a normal variable of type `int`.

Without having a variable of type `struct stack`, there does not exist a `size`, which belongs to `struct stack`. Likewise, there's no way you can access `size`, which is a member variable in `struct stack` directly [without using a structure variable of type `struct stack`] anywhere.

To summarize

**Answer 1:**

The error is not for replacing `const int size=10` with `s.size = 10`. It's rather from the next line,

```
s.a= malloc(size*sizeof(int));
              ^
              |
```

Where, no `size` variable is present when `const int size=10` is removed.

**Answer 2**

`const int size=10` declares and defines a new variable called `size`. It's not the same as the `s.size` [member of `struct stack`]. That's why using

```
s.a= malloc(size*sizeof(int));
              ^
              |
```

is valid, as a variable named `size` is in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as `size` is a structure variable, you have to access with the structure variable and initialize it.

if you initialize `size =10` it will take as a new variable. because init function will be stored in a separate stack and the scope of variable `size` will be inside the init function only.
Then while allocating the memory you should allocate for the `s.size` variable.

```
s.a = malloc(s.size * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

`s.size=10` has no problem. The problem is when you allocate memory for `s.a`, there's no variable named `size`, you should change it to:

```
s.a = malloc(s.size * sizeof(int));
```

You seem to be confused about the variable `size` and the member `size` in the structure `struct stack s`, they are not related except having the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: the following method of defining/declaring a struct is depreciated
struct stack
{
    int *a;
    int top;
    int size;
}s;

The preferred method is:
// declare a struct type, named stack
struct stack
{
    int *a;
    int top;
    int size;
};

struct stack s;  // declare an instance of the 'struct stack' type

// certain parameters to the compile command can force 
// the requirement that all functions (other than main) 
// have a prototype so:
void init ( void );

void init()
{

    s.size =10;
    // get memory allocation for 10 integers
    if( NULL == (s.a=(int*)malloc(s.size*sizeof(int)) ) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    s.top=0;    
} // end function: init
```